# Functional dependencies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to wrap my head around functional dependencies, but I am not getting anywhere on my own.  In the paper "Monad Transformers Step by Step", the author gives these two typeclasses definitions:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadError e m | m -> e where
    throwError :: e -> m a
    catchError :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a

class (Monad m) => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
    ask :: m r
    local :: (r -> r) -> m a -> m a
```

From my understanding of some of the material I found online, it means that the type variable `e` is determined by `m`.  I just don't understand what that means.  How is it determined?  Can anyone shed some light with minimal theory at first, and then link the more heavy theory stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you have a multiparameter typeclass, by default, the type variables are considered independently. So when the type inferencer is trying to figure out which instance of

```
class Foo a b
```

to choose, it has to determine `a` and `b` independently, then go look check to see if the instance exists. With functional dependencies, we can cut this search down. When we do something like

```
class Foo a b | a -> b
```

We're saying *"Look, if you determine what `a` is, then there is a unique `b` so that `Foo a b` exists so don't bother trying to infer `b`, just go look up the instance and typecheck that".* This let's the type inferencer by much more effective and helps inference in a number of places.

This is particularly helpful with return type polymorphism, for example

```
class Foo a b c where
  bar :: a -> b -> c
```

Now there's no way to infer

```
  bar (bar "foo" 'c') 1
```

Because we have no way of determining `c`. Even if we only wrote one instance for `String` and `Char`, we have to assume that someone might/will come along and add another instance later on. Without fundeps we'd have to actually specify the return type, which is annoying. However we could write

```
class Foo a b c | a b -> c where
  bar :: a -> b -> c
```

And now it's easy to see that the return type of `bar "foo" 'c'` is unique and thus inferable.

Answer (score 41):

It means that the type system will always be able to determine the type (`e` or `r`) from the type `m`.

Let's make our own example:

```
class KnowsA a b | b -> a where
    known :: b -> a
```

We should always be able to determine `a` from `b`

```
data Example1 = Example1 deriving (Show)

instance KnowsA Int Example1 where
    known = const 1
```

The type system knows that for this instnace, whenever it has an `Example1`, the type of it's `a` will be `Int`. How does it know? It doesn't allow us to have another instance with another type.

If we add

```
instance KnowsA [Char] Example1 where
    known = const "one"
```

We get an error:

```
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance KnowsA Int Example1
      instance KnowsA [Char] Example1
```

But we can add another instance with a different type for `a` if we have a different type for `b`

```
data Example2 = Example2 deriving (Show)

instance KnowsA [Char] Example2 where
    known = const "two"

main = do
    print . known $ Example1
    print . known $ Example2
```

This predictably outputs

```
1
"two"
```

Answer (score 29):

When Haskell is trying to resolve `MonadError e m` it, by default, scours both the `e` and `m` parameters together looking for any pair which happens to have an instance. This is especially hard if we don't have an `e` showing up anywhere in the type signature outside of the constraint itself

```
unitError :: MonadError e m => m ()
unitError = return ()
```

The functional dependency says that once we've resolved `m`, there can be only one `e` that works. That lets the above fragment compile as it reassures Haskell that there's enough information there for it to have a non-ambiguous type.

Without the functional dependency, Haskell would complain that `unitError` is ambiguous because it could be valid for any type `e` and we don't have any way to know what that type is—the information has somehow evaporated into thin air.

---

For `MonadError` the functional dependency usually means that the monad itself is parameterized by the error type. For instance, here's an instance

```
instance MonadError e (Either e) where
  thowError = Left
  catchError (Left e)  f = f e
  catchError (Right a) _ = Right a
```

Where `e ~ e` and `m ~ Either e` and we see that `m` does indeed uniquely identify a single `e` which could be valid.

---

Functional dependencies are "nearly" equivalent to Type Families as well. Type Families are sometimes a little easier to digest. For instance, here's a `MonadError` class, TypeFamilies style

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class MonadError m where
  type Err m
  throwError :: Err m -> m a
  catchError :: m a -> (Err m -> m a) -> m a

instance MonadError (Either e) where
  type Err (Either e) = e
  throwError = Left
  catchError (Left e) f  = f e
  catchError (Right a) _ = Right a
```

Here, `Err` is a type function which takes a `m` to its particular error type `e` and the notion if there being exactly one `e` equal to `Err m` for any `m` comes naturally from our understanding of functions.

Comment: +1 for Type Families. I think functional dependencies are more popular, not just because they are older, but because we get to keep using lowercase letters for things we imagine are type variables.

Comment: @Cirdec: you can always add `e ~ Err m` to your constraints to get such short lowercase type variables, though. I really like the resulting signatures, they are almost as concise as with `FunctionalDependencies` and at the same time as expressive as with `TypeFamilies`.