# How can I give the compiler a hint for picking the right instance function from a typeclass with several type variables?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a simple text cursor according to the custom `At` typeclass as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class At a b where
    valueAt :: a -> b
    moveOn :: a -> Maybe a

newtype AtText = AsAtText [Char] deriving (Show)

instance At AtText Char where
    valueAt (AsAtText []) = error "Unable to get a value from an empty list."
    valueAt (AsAtText (x:_)) = x
    moveOn (AsAtText []) = Nothing
    moveOn (AsAtText [_]) = Nothing
    moveOn (AsAtText (_:xt)) = Just $ AsAtText xt
```

So far so good, the problem I bumped into is when I tried to use the `moveOn` method later in code. So the compiler says it cannot infer which exact instance it should use asking me to provide a signature.

```
No instance for (At AtText b0) arising from a use of `moveOn'
  The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there is a potential instance available:
    instance At AtText Char
```

It is a valid point, but I have no idea how I can specify what the `b0` type variable is in a signature of `moveOn`

```
test :: AtText -> whatever
test at = 
    let nextAtOpt = moveOn at in -- <--- a probem
    case nextAtOpt of
        Just nextAt -> undefined
        Nothing -> undefined
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional dependencies in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040224/functional-dependencies-in-haskell)

Comment: @jozefg, if I knew what to search for (functional dependencies) I wouldn't ask a question. Although you are right, it turned out to be a duplicate.

Comment: You might also want to look up "type families" and "associated types" for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need are functional dependencies, you'll need to add the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}` and modify your class declaration to be

```
class At a b | a -> b where
    ...
```

What this does is instruct the compiler that for a given `a`, there is a unique `b` to match it with.  This means that you can't have another instance for `At AtText b` for `b` other than `Char`, though.

---

**Edit**: An alternative, as suggested by @shang and @MathematicalOrchid is to use Associated Types (if I've got this correct)

```
class At a where
    type B a :: *
    valueAt :: a -> B a
    moveOn :: a -> Maybe a

instance At AtText where
    type B AtText = Char

    valueAt (AsAtText [])    = error "Unable to get a value from an empty list."
    valueAt (AsAtText (x:_)) = x

    moveOn (AsAtText [])     = Nothing
    moveOn (AsAtText [_])    = Nothing
    moveOn (AsAtText (_:xt)) = Just $ AsAtText xt
```

and this requires the `TypeFamilies` extension.  There are a few variations on this pattern, but I'm not entirely sure on the differences.  For example, you can also define it as

```
class At a where
    type B :: *
    valueAt :: a -> B
    ...

instance At AtText where
    type B = Char
    ...
```

If someone else can elaborate, feel free to add the explanation as an edit, comment, or answer.

Comment: You may also be interested in reading about Associated Types, which provide an alternative way to encode this type of thing.