# Haskell type class confusion, inferred types cannot be deduced

Tags: haskell

Apologies, I dabble in Haskell in a minor way, once ever 2 years, and then I can't get my head around it.

Its best to just do the example.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


> class Foo a b where
>     foo :: a -> b
>     
> class Bar a b where
>     bar :: a -> b

> data A a = A a
> data B b = B b

> instance Foo (A a) a where
>   foo (A a) = a

> instance Bar (B b) b where
>   bar (B b) = b
```

so, what I THINK I'm doing is create to data types and then defining two functions based on the the membership of the datatype in the class....

so this works....

```
> f1 x = foo x
> f2 x = bar x

> x1 :: String
> x1 = f1 $ A "1"
> x2 :: String
> x2 = f2 $ B "1"
```

simple...

worry #1...if I remove the type declaration of x1 and x2, ghc complains

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘b1’ arising from a use of ‘f1’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Foo (A [Char]) b1)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include x1 :: b1 (bound at catdog.lhs:27:3)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b1’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance Foo (A a) a -- Defined at catdog.lhs:17:12
    • In the expression: f1 $ A "1"
      In an equation for ‘x1’: x1 = f1 $ A "1"
   |
27 | > x1 = f1 $ A "1"    |        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is a worry, isnt it obvious?...and this sort of thing will happen again.....

if I write

```
> f x = bar (foo x)
```

to me a perfectly reasonable thing...ghc agrees!

I ask it for the type...I get

```
f :: (Bar a1 b, Foo a2 a1) => a2 -> b
```

I can buy that.

like a good programmer I paste the type in

```
> f :: (Bar a1 b, Foo a2 a1) => a2 -> b
> f x = bar (foo x)
```

and "BOOM"...

```
• Could not deduce (Foo a2 a0) arising from a use of ‘foo’
      from the context: (Bar a1 b, Foo a2 a1)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   f :: forall a1 b a2. (Bar a1 b, Foo a2 a1) => a2 -> b
        at catdog.lhs:32:3-39
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        x :: a2 (bound at catdog.lhs:33:5)
        f :: a2 -> b (bound at catdog.lhs:33:3)
      These potential instance exist:
        instance Foo (A a) a -- Defined at catdog.lhs:17:12
    • In the first argument of ‘bar’, namely ‘(foo x)’
      In the expression: bar (foo x)
      In an equation for ‘f’: f x = bar (foo x)
   |
33 | > f x = bar (foo x)    |              ^^^^^
```

so ghc is telling me the type it inferred without a type declaration, its now not sure about!

now...there is usually one cog in my head that gets turned backwards by using scala or f# or some other OO style type system, that I have to turn the other way around....am I going mad?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert on any of this, but for worry #1 what I think is happening is that, when you omit the type signature, GHC is seeing that it needs to have an instance `Foo (A String) b` and can't figure out what `b` is. I guess it's not capable of seeing that your script has only one such instance in this case (with `b` being `String`) - if you had more than one then it would certainly have just cause to complain about an ambiguity.

Comment: as for the second one, this is even further away from my comfort zone, but I would guess that GHC has no idea what `a1` is, and can't read the constraints as saying "I want there to be some type `a1` for which the constraints `Bar a1 b` and `Foo a2 a1` hold simultaneously". Not sure how you could set this up (or if it's possible at all) so I will leave that to others more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your example again:

```
> class Foo a b where
>     foo :: a -> b
```

The problem here is that a given `a` could correspond to multiple given `b`s; you could have, for example, both `instance Foo Int Char` and `instance Foo Int Bool`. This causes the problems with type inference you've been seeing.

```
> f1 x = foo x
> f2 x = bar x

> x1 :: String
> x1 = f1 $ A "1"
> x2 :: String
> x2 = f2 $ B "1"
```

Here, for example, you've specified both `a` and `b`, so GHC knows you're talking about `instance (A String) String`. When you remove the signatures, GHC doesn't know what `b` to use. You haven't defined any other instances, and you don't intend to, but GHC doesn't know that.

So how do we fix this problem? We use `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}`:

```
> class Foo a b | a -> b where
>     foo :: a -> b
```

Basically, this tells GHC that for any given `a`, there is only one corresponding `b`. This should resolve your problems (although admittedly I haven't tested this yet). For more on functional dependencies, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040343/7345298), which also addresses your `bar (foo x)` problem.

Comment: Nice answer, I thought of Functional Dependencies (although it's something else I'm very inexpert on) but for some reason I momentarily (and incorrectly!) thought they were for type declarations rather than classes.

Comment: achchchc....of course...I have in a previous dabble into Haskell, done the dependent type stuff...the other way (type functions?) but yes...I completely get it....this cog is now engaged

Comment: as an aside....why does GHC infer a type, that it then afterwards rejects?

Comment: @MrD I don't quite understand what you're asking there - could you elaborate?

Comment: "so ghc is telling me the type it inferred without a type declaration, its now not sure about!"....in my original code, I ask GHCi for the type of f....and then paste the type into the code....but the GHC rejects this type.

Comment: @MrD The problem is that, although GHC knows there is a `Foo a2 a1` instance lying around, and that `x :: a2`, it doesn't know that you definitely want `foo x :: a1` and not, say, `foo x :: Int` or something else, hence it doesn't know to use the `Foo a2 a1` instance instead of, say, searching for a `Foo a2 Int` instance in its global list of instances. You can tell it what you want by adding an explicit `forall` to the type signature, `f :: forall a1 a2 b. (Bar a1 b, Foo a2 a1) => a2 -> b`, and adding a type annotation to the body, `f x = bar (foo x :: a1)`.

Comment: ok...I don't massive understand...but lets leave it there...more cogs need to reengage